# Simulator is not available error (Xcode 6.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-4

I am about to upload the latest version of my app to the App Store, however up until this point I haven't done a whole lot of testing on iOS 7.

When I go to use the simulator, I am getting the error:

> iPhone 4S is not available: Please select a different device and try again.

My deployment target is set correctly to 7.0.

Has anyone experienced this error? Any solutions?

[image: Screenshot for error]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have the iOS 7 simulators installed.  Navigate to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components and make sure the 7.0 and/or 7.1 simulators are downloaded.  If there are check boxes next to each simulator, click "Check and install now" to see if any simulators need to be re-downloaded.

Comment: I have the 7.0 simulators installed and it still doesn't seem to work. I'll try downloading the 7.1 simulators to see if they work.

Comment: I updated Xcode and apparently it erased my previously downloaded simulators. After installing it again everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

For those running Yosemite

The earliest simulator runtime supported on Yosemite is 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode, from the menu, select: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> iOS Simulator

When sim is open from the menu, select: Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices...

Click the + button, bottom left and add the devices/OSes you need.

Comment: Nope, the device/iOS combination is already there. I still get the error.